# Check for grafted commits in git?

Tags: git

I want to find the most recent non-grafted commit. My plan was to use `git log --oneline` and walk through the lines until I find one marked as grafted. This almost works; the file that pops up in vim looks as follows:

```
6a40aa9 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Commit 8
e7e139a (grafted) Commit 7
6ada9c8 (grafted) Commit 1
```

This is exactly the output I am looking for. However, the output flushed to stdout does not include the `grafted` tags. For example, `git log --oneline > file.txt` makes `file.txt`:

```
6a40aa9 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Commit 8
e7e139a Commit 7
6ada9c8 Commit 1
```

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong? Is there another or better way to find grafted commits?

Comment: Have you tried adding the `--decorate` flag when you redirect output? (If that works I'll make it an answer, but I'm unsure if that only works in my local quick test scenario.)

Comment: @msanford Yes that works! Thanks so much!

Comment: Yes: the default setting for `log.decorate` is `auto`, and `auto` means *when going to the user, but not when going to a file*, more or less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the [`--decorate` flag](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) to add annotations:

```
git log --oneline --decorate > file.txt
```